# Underscore indexOf within a Collection

Tags: backbone.js, comparator, indexof

I've been looking already around for the answer with no luck.
Basically I am reviewing again the Addy Osmani guide to Backbone, and it seems I can't get through this code here.

```
var people = new Backbone.Collection;

people.comparator = function(a, b) {
    return a.get('name') < b.get('name') ? -1 : 1;
};

var tom = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Tom'});
var rob = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Rob'});
var tim = new Backbone.Model({name: 'Tim'});

people.add(tom);
people.add(rob);
people.add(tim);

console.log(people.indexOf(rob) === 0); // true
console.log(people.indexOf(tim) === 1); // true
console.log(people.indexOf(tom) === 2); // true
```

I don't see how people.comparator can reorder the collection even though is not called anywhere, plus how comes that returning 1 or -1 can reorder it.
Or is it implicitly called once the Collection is created or indexOf is called on the Collection itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator):

> By default there is no comparator for a collection. If you define a
>   comparator, it will be used to maintain the collection in sorted
>   order. This means that as models are added, they are inserted at the
>   correct index in collection.models.

So every time you call `people.add(...)` the collection uses the comparator that you have set with `people.comparator = function(a, b) { ... }` to insert the model in an ordered position.

Comment: Thanks so much for the heads up!I was in fact unsure about the comparator function as is not mentioned on that lecture.